# MapReduce Distributed Cache

Tags: caching, distributed, mapreduce

I am adding a file to distributed cache of Hadoop using

```
     Configuration cng=new Configuration();
     JobConf conf = new JobConf(cng, Driver.class);
     DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path("DCache/Orders.txt").toUri(), cng);
```

where DCache/Orders.txt is the file in HDFS.

When I try to retrieve this file from the cache in configure method of mapper using:

```
    Path[] cacheFiles=DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
```

I get null pointer. What can be the error?

Thanks

Comment: I know the porblem is due to the path. How the path or URI has to be specified in the addCacheFile?? Is it absolute path. If I want to represent in the form of URI, how should I write it?

Comment: I am using single node cluster on windows.

Answer (score 1):

DistributedCache doesn't work in single node mode, it just returns a null pointer. Or at least that was my experience with the current version.

I think the url is supposed to start with the hdfs identifier.

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache

Comment: that should be at not with, so /user/folder/file rather than hdfs://user/folder/file